"The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" error when trying to acess a bucket in Minio in Great expectations
I'm completely new to Great Expectations.
I'm trying to access a bucket in Minio and execute some expectations but I'm getting the error:

The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Here's my datasource config in great_expectations.yaml:
  datalake_landing_datasource:
    class_name: Datasource
    module_name: great_expectations.datasource
    execution_engine:
      class_name: PandasExecutionEngine
      module_name: great_expectations.execution_engine
    data_connectors:
      default_runtime_data_connector_name:
        name: default_runtime_data_connector_name
        class_name: RuntimeDataConnector
        module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector
        batch_identifiers:
          - default_identifier_name
      default_inferred_data_connector_name:
        name: default_inferred_data_connector_name
        class_name: InferredAssetS3DataConnector
        module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector
        default_regex:
          pattern: (.*)\.csv
          group_names:
            - data_asset_name
        boto3_options:
          endpoint_url: http://127.0.0.1:9000/
          aws_access_key_id: admin
          aws_secret_access_key: admin12345
        bucket: datalake-landing

Using the code bellow, it is possible to see the content of the bucket:

but when I try to create a validate to then execute a expectation the error appears
Does anyone knows how to solve this please?

Supply valid, active AWS credentials. Check them with aws sts get-caller-identity.

It is saying that your Access Key / Secret Key is invalid. Where did you get them? How are you providing them to your code?

This could potentially be caused by a misconfiguration of minio. If you're accidentally using the real AWS S3 endpoint then your minio credentials, which are valid for minio only, will be invalid for the real S3 and cause this error message.

I am creating the key in minio and putting in the datasource sections in the yaml file
